# Oracle DB / ODI / OBIEE installation on Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, obiee, oracle-data-integrator, odb

I'm going to set up some machines, over cloud.google.com, and install Oracle Database, Oracle Data integrator, and also Oracle Business Intelligence on these machines.
As I don't have any experience in installing these services on google cloud, I would be thankful if you could help me and let me know what differences (configure and setup) against installing in physical machines?

Also, do we need to pay for Oracle services (ODI, DB, and OBI) to download them? or they're free to download? can we just download them directly from this machine?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Installing any software on GCP virtual machines is usually the same as doing it on physical machines.**

Just create one (or more VM's) and try installing it first to get "the feel" of how it's done. If you know how much resources your software needs then choose proper machine (number if CPU's, RAM, disk).

You will be able to access your VM's via SSH (using GCP's Console) or any SSH capable software. Port 22 is always open for any incoming connections from the Internet for your convinience. You can however restrict that using firewall rules or [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap).

I'm guessing that you want this software to be always available and have some sort of failover. In this case I recommend using [GCP's External TCP/UDP Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network) and [managed instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups) (you can specify number of machines you need - minum and maximum) and it will be scaled automatically - based for example on CPU usage or number of requests per second) as your backend.

You also need to set up some firewall [rules to allow traffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) on specific ports in [GCP Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#firewall_rules_in).

Since this software relies on a database engine you need to store it elsewhere and in this case you can use [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql).

You can control access to this service using either firewall rules, built in authorisation in your software or even using [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap).

If you haven't had any experience with the running your servers in the cloud please go through the documentation.

Ultimately - consider the cost of this setup (running VM's, network traffic, database usage, storage needed etc). You can use [Pricing Calculator](https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/) to get some estimates.

Regarding downloading software - you don't have to pay anything from the GCP's side and you can save it to your VM's (using for example `wget` command). As for the Oracle software itself - I'm not familiar with their licencing model so you have to manage it yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your professional and complete guide.as I claimed, I should install Database and Oracle data integrator as routine and same as a physical machine. Thanks again you're the best my friend